# Increase character width in Ubuntu server shell?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

Is there any way to increase the character width from 80 to something higher in the shell in an Ubuntu server?

Comment: You should provide a bit more detail. Are you accessing the server via ssh? VMware console? Are you running telnet from a macbook? Normally the character width is a client setting.

Comment: @Andy: Although I agree more information would be better, I think it may be deduced that Geuis is referring to a default desktop-less ubuntu server install which has a default 80 character limit.

Comment: @Andy ssh from macbook terminal to Ubuntu 12 server.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using ubuntu server you (presumably) do not have an X gui installed. Therefore, you need to increase your console resolution using grub.

**After checking that your monitor supports the resolution** you would like (see notes below), modify your default grub settings (`/etc/default/grub`) and specify the resolution as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash vga=795"
```

`vga=795` is the boot mode required to have a resolution of 1280x1024 with 24-bit color. This should double the number of characters from 80 to 160 (default is 640x480)!

For other resolutions and color depths check out the table on this page: [VGA Boot modes](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/vga-boot-modes-to-set-screen-resolution/)

**NOTE:**

1. Default is 640x480 for a reason - it's supported by almost every monitor.
2. 80 characters also has some historical reason (something to do with IBM punch cards) :)
3. Your monitor must support the resolution you pick so be prepared to test a few different boot modes in case the one you select does not work.
4. Heres how you can [test boot-options safely using a live cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)
5. There are several similar questions on [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299975/proper-way-to-change-terminal-resolution-in-ubuntu-server-13-04).